# Как оптимизировать работу Rails task?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, gems, swap

Есть Rails 5.0.0 проект, в котором очень много тасков. Все эти таски связаны как с простым обновлением данных в БД, так и с парсингом.

В Gemfile прописано почти 20 дополнительных гемов. Так или иначе, они где-нибудь да принимают участия в проекте.

Все это находится на сервере с 1Gb RAM и 1 CPU.

Когда Rails таски не запущены (кстати, их запускает CRON), то приложение живет себе нормально. Но как только запускается один, два или даже три таска (необязательно одновременно, достаточно чтобы их работа пересеклась), то ОЗУ быстро заканчивается, процессы начинают убиваться системой и так далее.

В принципе эту проблему решает SWAP. Но есть одно НО - проект и таски начинают тупить. Они очень медленно работают.

Теперь к сути вопроса.

Я выше писал про ~ 20 gem проекта. И ведь все эти gem'ы используются и таском, даже если они там не нужны, верно? Как для тасков указать свой персональный Gemfile (список gem'ов), чтобы таски не жрали столько ОЗУ (а то один таск может спокойно взять ОЗУ как Rails проект)?

Думаю, я более менее понятно изложил свою ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

Смотреть на SWAP файлы как на `серебряную пулю не стоит`. Все начинает тормозить при включении swap потому, что память забивается и пишется на диск, из-за чего не хватает памяти для остальных ресурсов. Надо смотреть куда память уходит.
Стоит подумать об комплексной оптимизации приложения и мониторинге. Количество гемов не показатель, может быть и 40. Было бы хорошо конечно взглянуть на сам Gemfile.

- В такой ситуации стоит подумать о том, что хорошо бы gems разнести по группа `test, develpment`, всегда находятся, которые можно перенести.
- Посмотреть о том, правильно запускаются Cron / Jobs / Workers, надо не забывать что в воркер надо передавать Id сущности, которую будем процессить в другом процессе.
- Стоит подумать для асинхронных задач использовать `redis`, чтоб не полить лишний раз базу, редиска штука легкая и много не ест ресурсов.
- Конечно не стоит забывать про простую оптимизацию N + 1 запросов, количество pool
- И по хорошему я бы еще посоветовал попробовать Puma сервер с настройкой воркеров и тредов 2 к 2, что более оптимально. Все же пума треды делает а не форк приложения.